# How to use already defined interface with io-ts library?

Tags: typescript, fabricjs, typescript-generics, fp-ts

I am using **@types/fabric** package in my application. I want to use predefined interfaces (like `ICircleOptions`, `IRectOptions` ..etc.) from fabric types.

How can I use these interfaces with **[io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/)** library for runtime typechecking.

I have defined a type like this:

```
const Response = t.type({
  id: t.number,
  type: t.string,
  objects: t.array(t.union([ICircleOptions, IRectOptions]))
})
```

I want to use fabric predefined interfaces to define the type for my objects array.

I have gone through https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/issues/209  and auther of **io-ts** has shared example there but not working in my case.

Please let me know, is it possible ? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You have to define a codec for the types provided by *fabric*. E.g.:

```
import * as t from "io-ts/Codec";
import { ICircleOptions } from "fabric/fabric-impl";
import { Either } from 'fp-ts/Either'

export const codecICircleOptions= t.type({ // or export const ICircleOptions if you like
  radius: t.number,
  startAngle: t.number,
  endAngle: t.number
});

export const example: Either<unknown, ICircleOptions> = codecICircleOptions.decode({})

// ....

const Response = t.type({
  id: t.number,
  type: t.string,
  objects: t.array(t.union([codecICircleOptions, codecIRectOptions]))
})
```

Comment: as readius, startAngle, endAngle is already defined in ICircleOptions from fabri-types. Then why do I need to write again codecICircleOptions for this ? they should come from the fabric-type

Comment: _fabric_ is just providing the type definition. Not the codec. Codecs are actual values, not types. Types are removed when compiling to JavaScript while codecs (objects with functions) remain.

Comment: While there's no way to use existing type/interface declarations as `io-ts` types directly (because, as mentioned, they don't exist at runtime), there are a couple of existing libraries for _generating_ the `io-ts` code from said declarations:

 - https://github.com/juusaw/ts-to-io
 - https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts-codegen

There may be more out there, but those are the two I know of. I've used `ts-to-io` a couple of times to help in porting over some of my pre-`io-ts` code to `io-ts`, but not super recently. YMMV